# Dart Can't get logging statements to compile

Tags: dart

I'm trying to learn how to implement logging using the examples/tutorial in:

http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/05/campaign-to-use-real-logging-instead-of.html#comment-form

But having imported the libraries this line in main will not compile because the class '*PrintHandler*' is not recognized and Google has not been a help in this case.  My server application consists of a main and three classes. I'm new at Dart.  Below I've extracted the logging code that I added.

In what library is '*PrintHandler*'?  Is this a class I need to write?

```dart
library server;

import 'package:logging_handlers/logging_handlers_shared.dart';
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';

final _serverLogger = new Logger("server"); // top level logger

void main() {
  Logger.root.onRecord.listen(new PrintHandler()); // default PrintHandler
  _serverLogger.fine("Server created");
}

class A {
}

class B {
}

class C {
}
```

Comment: I used logging_handlers for a while but I had the impression lately that http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver_log is a better option.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'll look into it.  It's certainly interesting working with a language that is still evolving ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the class was [changed](https://github.com/chrisbu/logging_handlers/commit/7ff9e200552c8c7ba274fd4e06aaffd918dc4250) to LogPrintHandler but the tutorial and documentation were not updated.

Comment: That's it, thanks.  Do you know if changes have been made to output to a file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. When you can't trust the documentation (due to being out of date) your best bet is to look directly at the source code to figure out what you need to call. (Or as Günter mentions, consider using a more up-to-date library.)